# Is it possible for MSI installer to install the files and terminate without leaving a foot print?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I use the old version of InstallShield just simply to copy the files to the local hard disk, and then to abort, so that thie installer doesn't create any foot prints, such as, HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{my GUID} and C:\Program Files\InstallShield Installation Information{my GUID}.

I want to change my installer to MSI, but I do not know if MSI can do the same thing, since all I know if I abort, MSI will rollback.

If I can do it with MSI, how can I do it?

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

No, the point of MSI is to integrate into Windows e.g. to allow for installed applications to be managed via Control Panel. Therefore, components installed via an .msi file always will leave a footprint in the Windows Installer database.

Answer (score 2):

How far do you want to take this?  Do you simply want to hide your product's entry in Add/Remove Programs or do you literally want MSI to not even remember that it's not installed?  I.E  no uninstall, repair, upgrading, patching.

If the desire is the former, take a look at the [ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367750%28VS.85%29.aspx).  If the desire is the latter you want to make a "Trojan MSI".  Note many experts are against this but I've done it on occassion as have teams at big companies such as Microsoft and Google.   To create a Trojan MSI you intentionally leave out the *Publish* standard actions in your installer such as the [PublishProduct Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370932%28VS.85%29.aspx).  You need to be really sure you understand what your goals are and what you are giving up in doing this but there are times when it makes sense.

Update:  The OP indicates the purpose is to patch installed MSI's.

This really shouldn't be done.  You should do proper updates / patches with MSI's and MSP's.   However, what you ask for can be done.  At a place that I have worked at they had something called the "not a patch, patch".  It's pretty ugly but does work.  Realize you'll never be able to repair the patch ( except to reapply it )  and you can also get into situations where repairing the MSI undoes the patch so you  have to apply the patch again.  Of course there's no uninstalling of the patch or versionining artifact for it in Add/Remove programs.

So yes, it can be done but I honestly don't suggest that you do it. I only "supported" it at that job because someone else put it into use and the business area had gotten used to it as a (fake)servicing pattern.